# DRF Serializer Fields are not showing in Openapi Schemas

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I set up openapi with the [drf-yasg package](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for my DRF API but for some reason, all endpoints for POST or PUT in my documentation are not showing the necessary fields required.
How can I set it up to show the necessary fields required to send data to the API, currently they don't show in the schema as well as the in generated  documentation for the API

Here's my code

#Project level urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from rest_framework import permissions # new
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view # new
from drf_yasg import openapi # new


schema_view = get_schema_view( # new
    openapi.Info(
        title="Blog API",
        default_version="v1",
        description="API for CaseMed Insurance",
        terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="hello@example.com"),
        license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
    ),
        public=True,
        permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/auth/', include('user.urls')),
    path("api/services/", include('services.urls')),
    path('swagger/', schema_view.with_ui( # new
    'swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path('redoc/', schema_view.with_ui( # new
    'redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from user.serializers import CustomerResponseSerializer


#############################
#### category serializers ###
#############################

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'name',
            'description'
        )

class CategoryUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            
        )

class CategoryResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'name',
            'description',
            'id',
            'created_by',
            'modified_by'
        )


#############################
#### product serializers ###
#############################


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'category',
            'description',
            'terms_and_conditions',
            'price'
        )

class ProductResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'name',
            'category',
            'description',
            'terms_and_conditions',
            'id'
        )





#######################################
#### Dependant serializers ###
#######################################


class DependantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dependant
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'other_names',
            'gender',
            'date_of_birth',
            'relationship'
            
        )


class DependantResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dependant
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'other_names',
            'gender',
            'date_of_birth',
            'relationship',
            'created_by',
            'modified_by',
            'id'
        )
```

Views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated

from .serializers import *
from .models import *

# Create your views here.

##########################
##### Category Views #####
##########################



class CreateCategory(APIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.user)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        valid = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if valid:
            new_category = Category(
                name=serializer.data['name'],
                description=serializer.data['description'],
                created_by=request.user
            )

            new_category.save()
            status_code = status.HTTP_201_CREATED

            response = {
                'success': True,
                'statusCode': status_code,
                'message': 'category created successfully!',
                'category': serializer.data
            }

            return Response(response, status=status_code)



class CategoryDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategoryResponseSerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class ListCategory(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategoryResponseSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class UpdateCategory(APIView):
    serializer_class = CategoryUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        valid = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if valid:
            update_category = Category.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])

            
            update_category.name = serializer.data['name']
            update_category.description = serializer.data['description']
            update_category.modified_by = request.user

            update_category.save()
            status_code = status.HTTP_201_CREATED

            response = {
                'success': True,
                'statusCode': status_code,
                'message': 'category updated successfully!',
                'category': serializer.data
            }

            return Response(response, status=status_code)
            


class DeleteCategory(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)





#########################
##### Product Views #####
#########################


class CreateProduct(APIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        valid = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if valid:
            linked_category = Category.objects.get(id=serializer.data['category'])
            new_product = Product(
                name=serializer.data['name'],
                category=linked_category,
                description=serializer.data['description'],
                terms_and_conditions=serializer.data['terms_and_conditions'],
                price=serializer.data['price'],
                created_by=request.user
            )

            new_product.save()
            status_code = status.HTTP_201_CREATED

            response = {
                'success': True,
                'statusCode': status_code,
                'message': 'product created successfully!',
                'product': serializer.data
            }

            return Response(response, status=status_code)


class ProductDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductResponseSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

class ListProduct(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset =  Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductResponseSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

class UpdateProduct(APIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        valid = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if valid:
            update_product = Product.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
            linked_category = Category.objects.get(id=serializer.data['category'])
            
            update_product.name = serializer.data['name']
            update_product.category = linked_category
            update_product.description = serializer.data['description']
            update_product.terms_and_conditions = serializer.data['terms_and_conditions']
            update_product.price = serializer.data['price']
            update_product.modified_by = request.user

            update_product.save()
            status_code = status.HTTP_201_CREATED

            response = {
                'success': True,
                'statusCode': status_code,
                'message': 'product updated successfully!',
                'product': serializer.data
            }

            return Response(response, status=status_code)

class DeleteProduct(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Generated Swagger Documentation

[image: Generated Swagger Documentation]

Comment: Hi @jordan-rob did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by replacing the `APIView` base class with `generics.GenericAPIView`

```
class CreateProduct(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    ...

class UpdateCategory(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategoryUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    ...
```

This is not an issue with the POST and PUT http methods.
The views that don't show the correct serializer are all inheriting from the APIView class, which unfortunately doesn't support the kind of introspection you need.
Quoting the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#autoschema):

> Note: The automatic introspection of components, and many operation parameters
> relies on the relevant attributes and methods of GenericAPIView: get_serializer(),
> pagination_class, filter_backends, etc. **For basic APIView subclasses**, default
> introspection is essentially **limited** to the URL kwarg path parameters for this reason.